# td class="name", why is it creating a html error 500

Tags: php, html

Trying to apply a td class name to each of the columns within the table, to identify it with the data. at the moment each td is contenteditable, when i add or change it to td class="name", on page reload it just crashes, why?

I have even tried closing php code, and opening again afterwards, but to no avail.

```
<tbody>
                    <?php               //BEGINNING OF PHP
                    include("login/dbinfo.inc.php");
                    $comm=@mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
                    $rs=@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

                    $sql="SELECT AwbNo, VesselName, ClientCode, Pieces, Weight, Carrier, Sender, Status, DATE_FORMAT(ArrivalDate, '%d-%m-%yyyy') FROM tbl_import";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
                    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    echo "<p>There are $num_rows records in the Customer table.</p>";

                    while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo ("<tr>\n");
                        echo ("<td class="awb">".$get_info["AwbNo"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["VesselName"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["ClientCode"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["Pieces"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["Weight"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["Carrier"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["Sender"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["Status"]."</td>");
                        echo ("<td contenteditable='true'>".$get_info["ArrivalDate"]."</td>");
                        ?>
                            <td>
                            <?php
                                echo '<a href="javascript:edit_user('.$get_info['awb']. ')">&nbspEdit&nbsp</a>';
                            echo '<a href="javascript:delete_user('.$get_info['AwbNo']. ')">&nbspDelete&nbsp</a>'
                                ?>
                            </td>
                        <?php
                        echo ("</tr>\n");
                    }
```

Comment: You need to escape characters - try this: "<td class=\"awb\""

Comment: Perfect, thank you Bogdan, that silly error had me scratching my head! the escape characters worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape the double quotes, so they will not be read as PHP code. You can do this by typing a `\` character before them.

```
\" $you_code \"
```